# Stanford CoreNLP version 4.2.0

Tags: stanford-nlp

Are there any migration hints about moving to v4.2.0? This page https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/migration.html is quite helpful but does not cover the current release.

FWIW, I revved my version from 4.0.0 to 4.2.0 and am now getting a lot of SUTime errors. This is running under Corretto java 11.

$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS, mixed mode)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse date string: [335-58-2020]
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.extractTimeExpressionCoreMaps(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:101)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier.runSUTime(NumberSequenceClassifier.java:345)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier.classifyWithSUTime(NumberSequenceClassifier.java:143)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier.classifyWithGlobalInformation(NumberSequenceClassifier.java:106)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.recognizeNumberSequences(NERClassifierCombiner.java:326)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.classifyWithGlobalInformation(NERClassifierCombiner.java:281)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifySentenceWithGlobalInformation(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:343)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.NERCombinerAnnotator.doOneSentence(NERCombinerAnnotator.java:554)
.....
Caused by: org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 58 for dayOfMonth must not be larger than 31
        at org.joda.time.chrono.BaseChronology.validate(BaseChronology.java:195)
        at org.joda.time.Partial.<init>(Partial.java:272)
        at org.joda.time.Partial.with(Partial.java:495)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.JodaTimeUtils.setField(JodaTimeUtils.java:284)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTime$IsoDate.initBase(SUTime.java:3371)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTime$IsoDate.<init>(SUTime.java:3347)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTime.parseDateTime(SUTime.java:3756)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.extractTimeExpressionCoreMaps(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:99)
```

Thanks

Comment: java 11 w/ corenlp 4.0.0 works without errors. 

I've also noticed some changes in behavior between 4.0 and 4.2 in my regression tests. For example the sentence:

We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.

Under 4.0.0 resting is tagged as JJ. Under 4.2.0 resting is tagged as NN.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any migration required for 4.2.0 it only contains small changes. Could you please let me know what examples generate those errors.

As for the part-of-speech tagging changes, we change the models from time to time, so that will cause changes such as that.